# I am getting T in my date string from web service

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services

I am creating an app which is using RSS feed.
in that I have to parse a dateTime string.
string coming in data is : **Tue, 17 Sep 2013T04:00:00 GMT**
I can not convert it into date because of that T b/w year and hour.

Can anyone please provide me the date format for this?

I am using formate like **EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ**

But it is giving null value

Comment: Why can't you convert it? It is a standard format. Did you try adding the `T` to the format? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations

Comment: There is no component like "T" in the formatting so you should ask your web developer that what it indicates and if unnecessary component then tell to remove it.

Comment: @Wain: That's not ISO-8601 - the T part is, but the "Tue, 17 Sep 2013" is not.

Comment: @JonSkeet, true indeed, the whole format is not ISO-8601 but the `T` is well described by the standard and the parsing requirements are similar

Comment: Use single quotes to indicate literal fields in a format:  `yyyy'T'HH`.

Comment: (It should also be noted that the date formatter frequently has difficulty with day names "tacked onto" incoming date strings, for reasons that are not entirely clear.  Sometimes it's best to strip off the redundant day name.)

Comment: Thanks all for helping me.
And @HotLicks : yah I used that just after posting question, that worked

Answer (score 1):

I used : EEE, dd MMM yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss ZZZ

and it worked..